# Nested subqueries built with NSExpression crashes but not its predicate

Tags: swift, core-data, subquery, nspredicate, nsexpression

I have some code that can recursively build nested subqueries with `NSComparisonPredicate` and `NSExpression`. Here it is when it's flat:

```
    // Nested subquery
    let entityPath = NSExpression(forKeyPath: "$s.mainUserResult.operations")
    let subQueryExpression = NSExpression(forSubquery: entityPath, usingIteratorVariable: "t", predicate: NSPredicate(format: "$t.operationType == 3"))
    let countSubQuery = NSExpression(format: "%@.@count", argumentArray: [subQueryExpression])
    let p1 = NSComparisonPredicate(leftExpression: countSubQuery,
                                 rightExpression: NSExpression(forConstantValue: 0),
                                 modifier: .direct,
                                 type: .greaterThan,
                                 options: NSComparisonPredicate.Options(rawValue: 0))

    // Main subquery
    let entityPath2 = NSExpression(forKeyPath: "sessions")
    let subQueryExpression2 = NSExpression(forSubquery: entityPath2, usingIteratorVariable: "s", predicate: p1)
    let countSubQuery2 = NSExpression(format: "%@.@count", argumentArray: [subQueryExpression2])
    
    let p2 = NSComparisonPredicate(leftExpression: countSubQuery2,
                                 rightExpression: NSExpression(forConstantValue: 0),
                                 modifier: .direct,
                                 type: .greaterThan,
                                 options: NSComparisonPredicate.Options(rawValue: 0))
```

The above code crashes when I fetch some entities with the following error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't have a non-relationship
> collection element in a subquerySUBQUERY($s.mainUserResult.operations,
> $t, $t.operationType == 3)'

What's really weird is that when I build a predicate by hand by copying the resulted `predicateFormat` of the NSComparisonPredicate, it actually works!

Fetching with the predicate `p2` results in an error, whereas fetching with the resulted format works:

```
   let p2 = NSPredicate(format: "SUBQUERY(sessions, $s, SUBQUERY($s.mainUserResult.operations, $t, $t.operationType == 3).@count > 0).@count > 0")
```

How to make the `NSComparisonPredicate` work?

Comment: `self` and keypath `$s.mainUserResult.operations` doesn't work. It should be variable `s` and keypath `mainUserResult.operations`. Try `let entityPath = NSExpression(format: "$s.mainUserResult.operations", argumentArray: [])`

Comment: That does work! Thanks a lot Willeke! Please post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSExpression(forKeyPath: "$s.mainUserResult.operations")`

does

`self.value(forKeyPath: "$s.mainUserResult.operations")`

This should be

`s.value(forKeyPath: "mainUserResult.operations")`

expression:

`NSExpression(format: "$s.mainUserResult.operations", argumentArray: [])`